# Proof involving conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-expectation

I am trying to prove or disprove the following: $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)^2]-\mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)]=0$. Using formulas for covariance or something like that just gives back the same problem.

Comment: Any definition for $E(X\mid Y)$? This could prove useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $E[X \mid Y]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable so that we may denote $E[X \mid Y]$ by $f(Y)$, hence
\begin{align*}
& E\{[E(X \mid Y)]^2\} \\
= & E\{f(Y)E[X \mid Y]\} \quad \text{ substitute one $E[X \mid Y]$ by $f(Y)$} \\
= & E\{E[f(Y)X \mid Y]\} \quad \text{ move $f(Y)$ inside to the inner conditional expectation as it is $\sigma$-$Y$ measurable}\\
= & E[f(Y)X] \quad \text{law of iterative expectation}\\
= & E[XE[X \mid Y]] \quad \text{ recall the definition of $f(Y)$}
\end{align*}

The result then follows.

Comment: I get the last step, but I do not see why the first equality holds. Could you please elaborate or give a reference?

Comment: OK, I will add more details